# Passing a java function as a parameter

Tags: java, wolfram-mathematica

I'm using Wolfram Mathematica 9.0 in my java application. The problem is that I need to generate a very long expression (something like 1.2 * (x-1) + 1.25 * (x-1.5) + ...etc.) as a function and it takes a long time to build it with StringBuilder. Are there any ways to pass a java function without converting it into a wolfram expression?

UPD

This function is what I am talking about. It builds the wolfram function exxpression. Usually, arr length is more than 100000.

```
public static String buildCdfExpressionForWolfram(double [] arr){

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    int n = arr.length;
    strBuilder.append("(");
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        strBuilder.append("HeavisideTheta[x");
        if(arr[i] > 0) {
            strBuilder.append("-");
            strBuilder.append(arr[i]);
        }
        else if(arr[i] < 0){
            strBuilder.append("+");
            strBuilder.append(-arr[i]);
        }
        strBuilder.append("]");
        if(i != n - 1){
            strBuilder.append("+");
        }
    }

    strBuilder.append(") / " + n);


    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: How long is 'a long time'?

Comment: Please specify how you are doing it now. Maybe by code snippet.

Comment: A long time is about 20-30 seconds. The problem is that this time is spent on building the expression and not on the calculation and it seems to me very illogical.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you reduce the amount of `append` call ?

```
public static String buildCdfExpressionForWolfram(double [] arr){

    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder("(");

    int n = arr.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(arr[i] > 0) {
            strBuilder.append("HeavisideTheta[x-"+arr[i]+"]");
        }
        else if(arr[i] < 0){
            strBuilder.append("HeavisideTheta[x+-"+arr[i]+"]");
        }
        if(i != n - 1){
            strBuilder.append("+");
        }
    }

    strBuilder.append(") / " + n);


    return strBuilder.toString();
}
```

Comment: I suppose, a + operator call is not much better than an append call.

Comment: Can you debug it and see which line hold the problems ? I've seen benchmark with that array length using stringbuilder taking less than a minute